# Initialise a List with foreach loop of items

Tags: c#, list

I am trying to set the value of object property which is of type List and initialise it by using a foreach to add the items to the list e.g.

```
var sessionPlanner = new SessionPlannerDTO()
        {
            Age = "",
            NumberOfPlayers = session.numberOfPlayers.Value,
            MedicalInformation = "",
            PlayerNeeds = "",
            SessionDate = session.daySessionDate.Value,
            Location = session.Location.locationName,
            PracticeView = new List<PracticeViewDTO>(foreach(var practice in session.Sessions){
                new PracticeViewDTO(){AbilityLevel = practice.ActivityPlan.abilityLevel.Value,
                ActivityUrl = practice.ActivityPlan.activityUrl,
                EquipmentNeeds = practice.ActivityPlan.equipmentNeeds,
                FacilityNeeds = practice.ActivityPlan.activityNeeds,
                HealthAndSafety = practice.ActivityPlan.healthAndSafetyIssues,
                SessionTitle = practice.ActivityPlan.activityName
                };
            })

        };
```

PracticeView is what I am trying to achieve by making it a list without doing the below:

```
var practiceViewList = new List<PracticeViewDTO>();
        foreach(var practice in session.Sessions)
        {
            var practiceX = new PracticeViewDTO()
            {
                AbilityLevel = practice.ActivityPlan.abilityLevel.Value,
                ActivityUrl = practice.ActivityPlan.activityUrl
            };
            practiceViewList.Add(practiceX);
        }
```

Comment: _"I am trying to"_ - so, what happens?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you don't want to do this? This is easily achievable with a Linq `Select` but the list is still going to be iterated either way.

Comment: Just because you _can_ write all your code in one big statement, doesn't mean you _should_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use other code than assignments in object or collection initializers. So your `foreach()` there won't compile.

Use `session.Sessions.Select()` to map the source entities to your DTO, and `ToList()` to create a list of the result:

```
sessionPlanner = new SessionPlannerDTO
{
    Age = "",
    // ...
    PracticeView = session.Sessions.Select(s =>
        new PracticeViewDTO
        {
            AbilityLevel = s.ActivityPlan.abilityLevel.Value,
            // ...
        }).ToList()
};
```

You also may want to consider using AutoMapper, instead of hand-writing mapping code.

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I didn't even think about that.